# Unity3D: Остановить анимацию

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос следующий: как мне остановить показ анимации при помощи элемента `Animator`? При реализации возникает проблема, поскольку при должной остановке анимации (когда GO уже остановился) она продолжается до тех пор, пока анимация не будет произведена полностью. В `Animator'e`настроил все условия, и транзакции.

Как вариант использовать `animation.Stop()`, только с этим у меня не получилось.

Вот пример кода требующего сей реализации:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("right");
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("left");
    }
    else if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Stop();
    }
```

Comment: а игра 2d или 3d? И хотелось бы узнать зачем все эти isLeft и isRight и что именно вы настроили в Animator'е? какие условия?

Comment: ну заходи, если что))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  а нет... показалось, увы. Анимация слишком короткая, я не уследил. Проблема остается прежней(анимация теперь вовсе не хочет проигрываться), только код я немного оптимизировал: `пример кода сверху`

Comment: всё же покажите настройки аниматора и что это за Left right? поворот персонажа в другую сторону или что? если менять направление персонажа на ходу - то для этого есть более простые действия........как хак, для сброса анимации можно сделать пустой `state` с именем `forceStop` например и когда анимация не нужна - сразу проигрывать этот стейт `.Play("forceStop");` ......... Вообще в аниматоре многое настраивается. например в зависимости от скорости передвижения будет проигрываться анимация бега или нет. нужно просто правильно написать условие............какова вообще задача в целом?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский целью было прекращение анимации, если никакая клавиша не была нажата. Т.е. возвращение к спрайту. Но сделать анимацию -- тоже решает мою проблему. Спасибо!